# A cleaner way for multiple conditions in a list comprehension

Tags: python, python-3.x, list-comprehension, text-processing

I have a list of words which I want to clean based on certain criteria. For example, remove a word if:

1. contains a dot
2. contains a number
3. contains certain noisy keywords (http, https in this case but can be extended)
4. is equal to `'s`
5. its length is less than 3
6. is a duplicate
7. is punctuation

I wrote the following code and it does the job, however, I think it's not very clean, especially if I add a few more conditions to it.

```
unique_words = []
    ([unique_words.append(word) for word in doc_new if word not in unique_words
      and word not in string.punctuation and not any([token.isdigit() for token in word])
      and word != "'s" and len(word) > 2 and 'http' not in word and 'https' not in word
      and '.' not in word])
```

test example:

```
['http:', 'edition.cnn.com', '2017', '10', '25', 'asia', 'xi', 'jinping', 'china', 'trump', 'index.html']
```

output:

```
['asia', 'jinping', 'china', 'trump']
```

Is there a better way to do this in a slightly cleaner way?

Note: Python 3.x

Comment: maybe you could find a regular expression for that... And you don't need the "'s" part because its smaller than 3

Comment: @FlorianH that's true. I will remove it in the final version.

Answer (score 0):

You can move filter criteria to another function

```
import string


def acceptance_function(word):
    if len(word) <= 3 or any([character in "0123456789." for character in word]) or 'http' in word:
        return False
    return True


items = ['http:', 'edition.cnn.com', '2017', '10', '25', 'asia', 'xi', 'jinping', 'china', 'trump', 'index.html']

filtered_items = filter(filter_criteria, items)

unique_items = list(set(filtered_items))

print unique_items
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd avoid chaining boolean operators and instead do something like this:

```
import string

ILLEGAL_CHARACTERS = "0123456789."
ILLEGAL_KEYWORDS = {"http", "https"}


def filter(iterable_of_words):
    filtered_words = []
    for word in iterable_of_words:
        if len(word) < 3 or any(char in ILLEGAL_CHARACTERS for char in word):
            # Word is less than three characters long,
            # or contains illegal characters (numbers, period).
            continue
        elif any(keyword in word for keyword in ILLEGAL_KEYWORDS):
            # Word contains an illegal keyword.
            continue
        filtered_words.append(word)
    return filtered_words
```

We can skip checking if the word is a single character, like `"s"` or is punctuation, because the word must be at least three characters long.

Answer (score 0):

You can use regex to simplify this. It can cover point 1,2,3,4,7 using below regex

r"[0-9.:;?!]|http|https|\'s|add|in|as|many|you|want"

Point 5 will automatically takes care of point 4 also.

```
import re
finallist = set()
for w in ['http:', 'edition.cnn.com','10', '2017', 'k10', '25', 'europe', '\'s', 'xi', 'jinping', 'china', 'trump', 'index.html']:
    if not (len(w)<3 or re.findall(r"[0-9.:;?!]|http|https|\'s|add|in|as|many|you|want", w)): finallist.add(w)
print finallist
```

Hope this helps